# send отправляет только строки?

Tags: c, сеть

Допустим я хочу отправить данные типа int:

```
int d=5;
send(sock,(void*)&d,sizeof(d),0);
```

на другом конце я их принимаю:

```
int *d;
recv(sock,d,sizeof(d),0);
```

но вывести число не получается.

Можно ли отправлять что-то кроме строк, например числа или структуры?

Comment: Закодируйте ваши числа или структуры в строку любым удобным способом и отправляйте. На стороне получателя раскодируйте.

Comment: @andreymal, то есть просто преобразовать тип `send(sock,(char*)&d,sizeof(d),0);`?

Comment: Я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что `(char*)&d` является каким-то внятным и стабильным кодированием.

Comment: И конкретно тут у вас код приёма неправильный. `int d; recv(sock,&d,sizeof(d),0);`

Comment: Однако такой подход не будет работать везде, потому что формат и размеры типа int могут отличаться на разных устройствах.

Comment: @andreymal, ой, косякнул с приемом

Comment: @andreymal, ну данные типа int можно переводить в сетевой формат, оказывается все дело было в коде приема и моей невнимательности, спасибо за помощь

Comment: `send` отправляет байты, а не строки, и ему без разницы что это за байты.

Answer (score 0):

Отправлять надо так:

```
int d = 5;
send(sock, &d, sizeof(d), 0);
```

Принимать так:

```
int d;
recv(sock, &d, sizeof(d), 0);
```

> Можно ли отправлять что-то кроме строк, например числа или структуры?

Второй параметр это адрес буфера, третий количество байтов в буфере. Можно отправлять любые байты, как вы их кодируете и декодируете — ваше дело.